# double quotes inside double quotes

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, web-config, connection-string

i am writing the following connection string into web.config
but it giving me error.what is the correct way to write it?

```
<add name="stargaze_stargazeConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="D:\Work At DS\19th Jan\myastrolove.com_new\App_Data\dbName.mdf";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

web.config is XML, so you need to escape the inner quotes to `&quot;`:

```
<add name="stargaze_stargazeConnectionString1" 
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=&quot;D:\Work At DS\19th Jan\myastrolove.com_new\App_Data\dbName.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
```

Comment: thanks @Oded its work fine for me.and thanks for urgent reply also.

Answer (score 2):

Inside the string, replace `"` with `\"` to properly escape it.

That means that your string should look like this:

```
"<add name=\"stargaze_stargazeConnectionString1\" connectionString=\"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=\"D:\Work At DS\19th Jan\myastrolove.com_new\App_Data\dbName.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True\"/>"
```

Comment: -1 - It's not a C# string - it's in web.config. This will still produce an error for the OP.

Comment: Seems I have misread the question. I did not see the web.config part. That makes your answer correct, so I'll upvote it.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't it be like:

```
<add name="stargaze_stargazeConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=\"D:\Work At DS\19th Jan\myastrolove.com_new\App_Data\dbName.mdf\";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
```